# Is important to protect routes on mobile devices exactly?

Tags: flutter, routes, protected

I want to create a mobile app, only mobile devices from the app and play store, and I have a protected area for administrators, is important to protect them? The app will be reserved only for mobile devices, URL structure is not important.

There should not be a way to enter (clicking by button for example) the admin area without rendered element.
For example, for the administrator will exist a "link" (or a button) to the admin area, for other users, not.

What do you think?
Any ideas and suggestions.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Protecting client routes is not important, but never leave server routes unprotected.

Of course from the usability point of view the basic user should never see admin functionality, but even if that would happen e.g because of bug, the user shouldn't be able to execute any admin tasks.